# Zend debugger and Eclipse with IIS on Windows 8

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, zend-framework, iis

I have installed PHP 5.3.28, Zend debugger and Eclipse (Kepler) on Windows 8.1 x64 with IIS 8.5 enabled. Debugger installation should be correct as I can see it in phpinfo() output

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
   with Zend Debugger v5.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2010, by Zend Technologies
```

php.ini settings are

```
[Zend]
zend_extension="C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/ext/ZendDebugger.dll"
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1/32,10.0.0.0/8
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=2
```

and dummy.php is in document root.

When I test it from Eclipse's Debug configuration page, it tries to connect to 127.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.10 (IP of localhost) and times-out. IIS log shows that dummy.php is requested and returns 200.

So it can not connect to localhost, but when I try it from another computer in my network (after opening port 10000 in the firewall), it connects just fine and I can debug webapp hosted on 10.0.0.10.

Can it be Windows 8 specific problem or am I missing something obvious? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

Comment: Yes, I did try 'always','1' and all the other options, but it's still the same.

Comment: Did you check your proxy settings ?

Comment: I don't use any proxy, so I did not check that. Where should I look?